# Jest + Nock: How to fail a test if a non-mocked request is made?

Tags: jestjs, nock

I have a test that is passing. However, I actually want it to fail because Nock is complaining about an API call that I have not mocked.

```
console.error node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:55
    Error: NetConnectNotAllowedError: Nock: Disallowed net connect for "localhost:80/client/api/v2/claims/categories?employee_wallet_id=5cc7f9432e041785dea91a7a"
        at Object.dispatchError (/Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/twic/twicapp-client/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:63:19)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/twic/twicapp-client/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:655:18)
        at Request.emit (events.js:412:35)
        at Request.emit (domain.js:470:12)
        at ErroringClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/twic/twicapp-client/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/http-request.js:121:14)
        at ErroringClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
        at ErroringClientRequest.emit (domain.js:470:12)
        at ErroringClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/twic/twicapp-client/node_modules/nock/lib/intercept.js:241:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) undefined

 PASS  src/components/ClaimNew/index.test.js
  when pretax account is chosen
    ✓ claimant input is shown (1065ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        4.325s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/components\/ClaimNew\/index.test.js/i.
```

Is there a way to configure nock to fail my test if a non-mocked request is made?

Answer (score 0):

Jest actually uses Jasmine, so you can use fail just like before.

Usage:

```
fail('you have failed me');
```

Here's the definition from the TypeScript declaration file for Jest:

```
declare function fail(error?: any): never;
```

Now to explicitly fail a test for some reason you can use `fail` within your test like:

```
try {
  await someOperationRelated_to_nock();
  fail('It should fail since nock is complaining!');
} catch (error) {
  console.log('It never came here!');
}
```

Update: you can also explore https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror